# Nvidia 3d vision not activating automatically

Tags: pc, stereo-3d

When I start a game (like SW:TOR for example), the screen shows the dual image for my 3d vision, but the glasses are not activated. To make it work, I have to go to nvidia control panel, 3d section and change the '3d display device' (or something) from 'nvidia 3d discovery' to my monitor, but I have to do this every time I restart the computer.

This didn't happen a few months ago, but guess something changed (some patch or nvidia drivers).  Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a SW:TOR problem. I've been playing other games like Mass Effect 3 and it always activates 3d vision correctly. Probably a TOR bug